# How to expose a base class only as const reference

Tags: c++, inheritance, const-correctness

I want my class `Foo` to expose it's base class `Bar` only as a const reference to `Bar`. This would mean that the members of `Bar` could be read, but not set.
This is what I've tried:

```cpp
struct Bar
{
    int member;
};

class Foo : protected Bar
{
public:
    operator const Bar&() { return *this; }
};
```

But when using this, following problem arises:

```cpp
int getBarMember( const Bar& bar )
{
    return bar.member;
}

int main()
{
    Foo myFoo;

    const Bar& refBar = myFoo; // C2243
    // const Bar& refBar = (const Bar&) myFoo; // always need to cast explicitly

    int read = refBar.member;

    int readByFunction = getBarMember( myFoo ); // C2243
    // int readByFunction = getBarMember( (const Bar&) myFoo ); // always need to cast explicitly
}
```

I want to be able to call functions that take const references to `Bar` without explicit casts.

The Compiler Error is:

> C2243: 'conversion type' conversion from 'Foo *' to 'const Bar&' exists, but is
> inaccessible

Comment: Is my wording "const reference to `Bar`" correct, or should it be more precisely "reference to const `Bar`"?

Comment: Everyone will understand "const reference to" even if it's not 100% precise. No need to worry about that.

Comment: there is no danger of confusion because references are implicitly const, you cannot rebind them. Colloquially there is no difference between "const reference" and "reference to const", at least not that I am aware of

Comment: I suggest to make the `operator Bar` public, read the error message and post it. Currently it looks like this could be closed as a typo, but it is not just a typo. Currently the error is due to your operator being `private`, but thats the minor problem

Comment: right, in my real application I had it public. But with public conversion operator, it still doesn't work. I've updated the compiler error, it's somehow trying to cast from `Foo*`, which I don't understand.

Comment: please do not mix working code with error for code that needs removal of `//`. Anything one has to change on your code to reproduce the error is a source of misunderstanding and confusion. Best is you post the code that reproduces the error and the verbatim complete compiler error message

Comment: what i mean is this: https://godbolt.org/z/9TaaMx3TK no errors. Now different compilers produce different errror messages. I have to be really lucky to find the same compiler, version and remove the right `//` to know exactly what you are talking about

Comment: When I compile this with clang 14 I get this warning: "Conversion function converting 'Foo' to its base class 'Bar' will never be used" So I guess the implicit reference conversion to Bar will always be a better match than the user defined conversion and then after the compiler has decided which conversion to use it discovered that the conversion is not available due to protected inheritance. So most likely all you can do is wrap the non mutating interface of Bar within Foo. Also when accessing foo.member where foo is a reference to Foo no user defined conversion functions will be applied.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number OK, I made the compiler error visible directly, thank you for your input.

Comment: A more verbose alternative would be `auto as_Bar() -> Bar const& { return *this; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, gcc and clang issue the following warning on the operator :

> ```
> <source>:12:5: warning: converting 'Foo' to a reference to a base class 'Bar' will never use a type conversion operator [-Wclass-conversion]
>   12 |     operator const Bar&() { return *this; }
>      |     ^~~~~~~~
> ```

If it's possible in your real code, you could use [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) principle and do the following ([see it online](https://godbolt.org/z/TM9Ea5s9j)):

```
struct Bar
{
    int member;
};

class Foo 
{
public:
    operator const Bar&() { return parent; }
protected:
    Bar parent;
};
```

It will probably require some changes in the way you access `Bar` within `Foo`, but it will work without casts for the outside world.

Comment: Very good alternative way of expressing the relationship between them, I'll use this in my application now.